# symfony 3 doctrine porting data from mysql to postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, symfony, database-migration

I have a website build with Symfony3 and MySQL.
Now I must migrate from MySQL to Postgres for specials needs.

I've found this tool for migrate it automatically ([nmig](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/nmig)), and all it was all done, no problem found! YEAH!

I've changed my app/config/parameters.yml as symfony documentation tells.

Cache cleared!

But when I try to execute a simple query from symfony form index, I get this error:

An exception occurred while executing

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_0, MIN(sclr_25) AS dctrn_minrownum
FROM (
      SELECT c0_.ID AS id_0,
             c0_.RAG_SOCIALE AS rag_sociale_1,
             c0_.INDIRIZZO AS indirizzo_2,
             c0_.CIVICO AS civico_3,
             c0_.CITTA AS citta_4,
             c0_.PROVINCIA AS provincia_5,
             c0_.NAZIONE AS nazione_6,
             c0_.SETTORE AS settore_7,
             c0_.REFERENTE1 AS referente1_8,
             c0_.REFERENTE2 AS referente2_9,
             c0_.CAP AS cap_10,
             c0_.EMAIL1 AS email1_11,
             c0_.EMAIL2 AS email2_12,
             c0_.PIVA AS piva_13,
             c0_.PATHLOGO AS pathlogo_14,
             c0_.TELEFONO AS telefono_15,
             c0_.NOTE AS note_16,
             c0_.VALORE_OFFERTE_TOTALI AS valore_offerte_totali_17,
             c0_.VALORE_OFF_ORD_ATTIVE AS valore_off_ord_attive_18,
             c0_.VALORE_FATTURE_TOTALI AS valore_fatture_totali_19,
             c0_.BANCA_APPOGGIO AS banca_appoggio_20,
             c0_.CONDIZIONI_PAGAMENTO AS condizioni_pagamento_21,
             c0_.RELATIVEID AS relativeid_22,
             c0_.created_at AS created_at_23,
             c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_24,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c0_.ID DESC) AS sclr_25
        FROM clienti c0_
    ) dctrn_result
    GROUP BY id_0
    ORDER BY dctrn_minrownum ASC
    LIMIT 10
    OFFSET 0

**SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERRORE: la colonna c0_.id non esiste
LINE 1: ...d_0, MIN(sclr_25) AS dctrn_minrownum FROM (SELECT c0_.ID AS ...
^
```

500 Internal Server Error - InvalidFieldNameException**

Same error if I try this query into sqleditor: same error!

What's wrong on my configuration??

Thx

Comment: Did you try to run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see if there were modifications to apply to the database before?

Comment: I don't have Postgres. So I'm not sure what is wrong, but could this be the problem: https://github.com/nette/database/issues/12

Comment: Finally I've found what's wrong! Debugging nmig migration project, I've seen that postgres table/column creation was make with ' around table and column name.
So, If I remove ' char, table and columns are done and doctrine queryies works fine! Thx all